# Bootstrap Carousel Control By List Items

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, controls, carousel

My question is about how to control bootstrap carousel by list items.

I have more than three list items. Each list item has a content inside of carousel area. What I want is to control these contents by clicking list items which are the headings of these contents. I think this could be achieved by  jquery but i couldt find any sample. Here is what I mean more clearly.

This is my list items.

```
<div  class="sub-menu-list"style="position:absolute">
<ul style="display:inline;">
         <li><a href="#purpose-content">purpose</a></li>
         <li><a href="#chronology-content">chronology</a></li>
         <li><a href="#services-content">services</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact-content">contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is carousel content

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active" id="purpose-content">    
   ... 
</div>
```

... 
    
  
       ... 
    
  
       ...

How to view each carousel content when its list item is clicked? For example i am in contact page and clicked chronology link, It is supposed to slide two times automatically backward or forward to view cronology content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this within your carousel, it'll work. Well as long as you have the bootstrap css/js files and jquery. All this will take care of the slide to animations between the different images.

```
<div class="carousel" id="myCarousel">
 <div class="inner-carousel" data-interval="3000" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="item active">
         <!-- example of what goes in here -->
         <img src="img.jpg">
         <div class="carousel-caption">title</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

And to fully answer your question, the moment you click on an 'li', the on click event to trigger the animation to the next image will occur.